# Caching new(movie) objects in found query data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I'm still new so please bear with me. I've looked, searched , googled and read but my brain is a bit fried now:(.

### **The Project**

A simple ASP.NET MVC project that uses search box to find information on youtube and opendb. This information is being collected and put in my movie object.

```
public ActionResult Search(string query)
        {
            movielist = new List<Movie>();
            TrailerApi _trailerapi = new TrailerApi();
            movielist.Add(_trailerapi.GetTrailerInformation(query));
            return View(movielist);
        }
```

Unfortunately I do not get the desired result. Instead the cache keeps populating a new object (empty movie object)and I wish for it to keep adding objects.

### My Desire

I wish to cache each result I find in a cache object and be able to first look for my movies inside this cache and then start using my API. 
So suppose I look for toy story first, then kung fu panda and last star trek, my cache will contain all 3 movies.

I'm pretty sure this guy has got what I want and I love his elegant solution.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1246/inmemory-caching-aspnet-mvc-6-core

But because I'm a noob I cannot open his project and getting this error 
https://postimg.org/image/9z5u52vt5/

### What I have tried

I created a CacheHelper class

```
public static class CacheHelper
{
        public static object GetValue(string key)
        {
            MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
            return memoryCache.Get(key);
        }
        public static bool Add(string key, object value, DateTimeOffset expr)
        {
            MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
            return memoryCache.Add(key, value, absExpiration);
        }
        public static void Delete(string key)
        {
            MemoryCache memoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
            if (memoryCache.Contains(key))
            {
                memoryCache.Remove(key);
            }
        }   
}
```

Then I tried to do this in my controller

```
      movielist = new List<Movie>();
       TrailerApi _trailerapi = new TrailerApi(); 
       movielist.Add(_trailerapi.GetTrailerInformation(query));
       CacheHelper.Add("movies", movielist, `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1));                                      
       return View(movielist);
```

### My Questions

- How can I achieve my desire in a clean way?
- Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: You code keeps initializing a new instance of `List<Movie>`. You need to check if the collection exists in the cache, and if so add it to that collection and use that collection in your view.

Comment: So I first need to check if the collection exists in cache and if not create a new collection and then add it to the cache? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, exactly - `List<Movie> model = CacheHelper.Get("movies") as List<Movie>; if (model == null) { model = new List<Movie>(); } ......`

Comment: aaah super. Told you my brain was fried ;). Thanks!